# Setting a multilanguage site in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, multilingual

I'm trying to set up a multilanguage site with typo3, but Im having some trouble. The default language of the site is German, but I also want to have it in English and French. So I went to define 2 more languages: English with ID=2 and French with ID=3

Next I added this typoscript to my template:

```
config.linkVars = L
config.uniqueLinkVars = 2
config.sys_language_overlay = content_fallback
config.language = de
config.locale_all = de_DE
config.htmlTag_langKey = de-DE
config.sys_language_uid = 0

[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
config.language = en
config.locale_all = en_EN
config.htmlTag_langKey = en-EN
config.sys_language_uid = 2

[globalVar = GP:L = 3]
config.language = fr
config.sys_language_uid = 3
config.locale_all = fr_FR
config.htmlTag_langKey = fr-FR
[end]
```

And then I added this language menu, from the extension [srlanguagemenu](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/sr_language_menu):

```
10 < plugin.tx_srlanguagemenu_pi1
10{
    languagesUidsList = 0,2,3
    defaultLayout = 2
    showLinkWithFlag = 0
    showCurrent = 1
}
```

But the menu only shows "English". This is the exact markup:

```
<div class="tx-srlanguagemenu-pi1">
    <div class="CUR"><img src="typo3/gfx/content_client.gif" alt="" style="width:7px; height:10px;"><a href="index.php?id=46">English</a></div>
    <div class="SPC"> &nbsp; </div> <div class="INACT"></div>
    <div class="SPC"> &nbsp; </div> <div class="INACT"></div>
</div>
```

Also. In the menu, the name of the pages doesn't show the translated version.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually have any translated page? Can you access it with ?L=xxx?

Comment: Probably, the best it's to make Your own menu with TS ?

Comment: Yes. Of course I have my content translated. How could I make the menu with TS?

Comment: Are 2 and 3 actually the uids of the sys_language records on the page tree root?

Comment: Yes, exactly. 2 is for english and 3 is for french. 0 is for German (default). I made another one before, but I deleted it (Thats why there no uid = 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to translate not only the content of your page, but also the page. This is done via creating an "alternative_page_language" ("alternative Seitensprache" in german).

You can create an multilanguage TS menu via [HMENU.special = language](http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/core-documentation/doc_core_tsref/4.7.0/view/1/7/#id784990).

For working with translations, have a look at the INFO-Modul. There is a "Localization Overview", don't miss it:) I guess you already found the language View in the Page Modul.

Comment: but you can see your translated content via adding the L-Parameter? And add an wrap to get some output for object 15 anyway. Just for being sure, that it gets rendered.

Comment: Using the L parameter does NOT show me my translated content :( I am wrapping it already. I took it off the pastebin for cleanness purposes

Comment: So, dont fiddle with the MENU if the L-Parameter does not work. check config.sys_language_uid in your configurations. Does it fit with the language records?

Comment: Ok, there was an error in the configuration. Now it shoes the content translated (but the page title doesnt translate in the menu)

Comment: Fixed, now the L parameter works alright. Now the menu shows the name of the page title 3 times, one in each language. How can I make that it shows the name of the languages instead?

Comment: Ok I solved that too :) Now there's one last problem. If I click on a page without english translation, the content shown is "German" (which is the correct behaviour) but the menu items are also shown in German. Isnt it possible to show it still in English? Or does the WHOLE page has to revert to German?

Comment: there is a large table which describes which setting has which effect (perhaps download the manual)  http://typo3.org/documentation/document-library/guides/doc_l10nguide/1.1.0/view/