# Custom language TYPO3 site

Tags: localization, customization, typo3, typoscript, multilingual

I've been searching everywhere without any success for the possibility to add a custom language to my TYPO3 site.
I would like to add Chinese/English with English as the language but a customized URL, Flag and Language name. The website is running TYPO3 v4.5.4 and upgrading is out of the question (If that would be suggestion).

**Tl;dr** A new flag and a new language name needs to be added to TYPO3 (To be used in front-end).

Comment: You should at least update to the latest version of the 4.5 branch. Your installation is otherwise a security risk.

This is a duplicate of the post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575060/setting-a-multilanguage-site-in-typo3

Answer (score 0):

For how to work with languages in TYPO3 CMS, please see the link the the comment to your question.

For adding a language, please refer to the documentation which also includes examples to add custom fallbacks between languages.
http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/Internationalization/Translation/Index.html#xliff-translating-languages

Answer (score 0):

@frontend Multi-language

1) Create new Website Language on root level
     - Add your language name, select flag
2) Localization view:
     - Show page language version: (Add your page language)
     - Edit page properties: (select your language flag)

Typoscript:
@page config

## Set the default label and flag

```
mod.SHARED.defaultLanguageLabel = English
mod.SHARED.defaultLanguageFlag = gb
```

@Fontend menu for language

## Language Menu

```
menu.lang_menu = COA
menu.lang_menu {
    10 = HMENU
    10 {
        special = language
        special.value = 0,1
        1 = TMENU
        1 {
            expAll = 0
            wrap = |
            NO = 1
            NO {
                stdWrap.cObject = TEXT
                stdWrap.cObject {
                    value =  EN||/DE

                } 
                allWrap = <span>|</span>
            }
            #RO < .NO
            #RO = 1
            #RO.ATagParams = class="hover"

            ACT < .NO
            ACT = 1
            ACT {
               allWrap = <span class="selected">|</span>
               #doNotLinkIt = 1
            }            
            CUR < .NO
            CUR = 1
            CUR {
               allWrap = <span class="selected">|</span>
               #doNotLinkIt = 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this post your help:)