# how to add new translation file in typo3

Tags: typo3

My defaut language is English, i have already a German xlf translation files for some pages and it's working perfectly, i tried to add a French translation so i copied the whole de.blabla.xlf file and change it to fr.blabla.xlf, and changed the field target-language="de" into fr.
but it didn't work!
this is the first 3 lines of the file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff version="1.0" xmlns:t3="http://typo3.org/schemas/xliff">
<file source-language="en" target-language="fr" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2011-10-18T18:20:51Z" product-name="my-ext">
```

what else i have to do to make the language file working?
Thank you in advance

Comment: my first question: do you actually have french as website language" ?
Click on list view > click on "root" in pagetree and look how many "Website language" records are there.

Comment: yes i have it in website languages

Answer (score 1):

For create new translation file follow below steps.

1. Create language for this file. click on LIST->ROOT and click Plus icon.
2. Add Language Configuration

---

```
[globalVar = GP:L = 3]
config.language = fr
config.sys_language_uid = 3
config.locale_all = fr_FR
config.htmlTag_langKey = fr-FR
[end]
```

3. create language file. `fr.locallang.xlf`. like below.

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<xliff version="1.0">
    <file source-language="de" target-language="fr" datatype="plaintext" original="messages" date="2015-05-06T16:16:41Z" product-name="extension_key">
        <header/>
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="sheet_titke">
                <target>Galería</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

---

Comment: after added this file once install / uninstall extension and remove temp file + clear all cached.

Comment: Also **note** that your target-language fiel is fr in language file

Comment: and which temp files there are alot of them?

Comment: Remove typo3temp folder and clear Install TOOL cache

Comment: install / uninstall your custome extension in whitch to added this language file

Comment: @OdayBanihani about the temp files to remove, it should be sufficient to remove the folder /typo3temp/var/Cache/Data/l10n

Comment: @OdayBanihani I also assume that you also have added the relevant TypoScript code for the french language
(check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575060/setting-a-multilanguage-site-in-typo3)

Comment: If all steps are done flush system caches which you can found under the flash icon.